# Monitoring of dynamic(scale up/down) kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, monitoring, scaling, telegraf, jmxtrans

We are using kafka cluster and we want monitor this cluster.

Current our approach:

1. collect jmx metrics (`telegraf jolokia plugin` or `jmxtrans`)
2. store into influx
3. render via grafana

But we faced with problem of static configuration of kafka broker's list.
We can configure only static list via `Jmxtrans` or `Telegraf jolokia plugin`.

We would like dynamic list (example configure only kafka cluster zookeeper connection for getting brokers list in each iteration of collecting metrics) for case scaling up/down of kafka.

May be do exist another instruments for monitoring dynamic kafka cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My finally solution next:

1. Custom bash input plugin (because i don't want build own telegraf with one custom go input plugin and I know not very well go language now:) )
2. In bash plugin `zkCli` is used for all kafka nodes discovery
3. Next bash script post bulk `jolokia` requet to each kafka node, aggregates and format to influx plugin.